# PHP foreach - Loop Through Array in Opposite Order

Tags: php, foreach

Is there a way to loop through a foreach loop opposite to the way it normally goes? For example, I have an unknown amount of files in the $_FILES variable ($_FILES['file'], $_FILES['file2'], $_FILES['3'] etc...). Using this code

```
foreach($_FILES as $i)
```

$i will output as file3, file2, file. I need it to output file, file2, file3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way without using a `for`:

```
$i = count($_FILES);
while ($i-->0)
    // Do stuff
```

I think it's ever so slightly prettier.

*Some years later, I look back at this and I frown.*

Comment: Maybe if you added some spaces and did pre-decrement :)

Comment: No no no, I like it better this way. It works, and it looks like an arrow. That alone makes it better. It's sort of the hipster loop. It's a bit obscure; you probably haven't heard of it. It's much more poetic than those other mainstream for loops.

Comment: You're totally right. I haven't heard of writing obscure code that is difficult to read for future developers. Very hip man!

Comment: This will only work if the array is numerically indexed, which it doesn't appear to be in the question. It is also hard to understand and therefore not easily maintainable, which in itself deserves a downvote.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check your sense of humour at the door.

Comment: I used a modified version of this.

Answer (score 6):

[array_reverse](http://php.net/array_reverse) should do the trick:

```
foreach(array_reverse($_FILES) as $i)
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(array_reverse($_FILES) as $i)
```